# Retuning a value for null records on a left outer join in an Access query

Tags: ms-access, left-join

I have tried all the formulas for returning a value in this situation and keep getting an error telling me I have the wrong number of arguments. Here is my query:

```
SELECT [ER Root].[Network Indicator], 
[ER Root].[Prov Indicator], 
[ER Root].[Pos Indicator], 
[ER].[ER Visit]
FROM [ER Root] LEFT JOIN ER ON ([ER Root].[Network Indicator] = ER.[Network Flag]) AND ([ER Root].[Pos Indicator] = ER.[POS Indicator]) AND ([ER Root].[Prov Indicator] = ER.[Category Indicator]);
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT [ER Root].[Network Indicator], 
[ER Root].[Prov Indicator], 
[ER Root].[Pos Indicator], 
ISNULL([ER].[ER Visit],0) AS "ER Visit"
FROM [ER Root] LEFT JOIN ER ON ([ER Root].[Network Indicator] = ER.[Network Flag]) AND ([ER Root].[Pos Indicator] = ER.[POS Indicator]) AND ([ER Root].[Prov Indicator] = ER.[Category Indicator
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Access' `ISNULL` function accepts only one argument and returns a boolean value.

If you want to return `0` when `[ER Visit]` is Null, you can use `Nz` in a query run from within an Access session.

```sql
SELECT Nz([ER Visit], 0) AS ER_Visit
```

Note, I used `ER_Visit` as the alias because the db engine may complain about a "circular" reference if you attempt to re-use the field name as an alias.

If you are running the query from outside an Access session (like from classic ASP or .Net), the `Nz` function will not be available.  You can do this instead ...

```sql
SELECT IIf([ER Visit] Is Null, 0, [ER Visit]) AS ER_Visit
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a few errors in your SQL code:

- `ISNULL` isn't a two argument function, it merely evaluates if a (variant) value is NULL and returns a `Boolean` value (`True` or `False`). The function you're searching for is `NZ`:

> You can use the Nz function to return zero, a zero-length string ("
>   "), or another specified value when a Variant is Null. For example,
>   you can use this function to convert a Null value to another value and
>   prevent it from propagating through an expression.

The second problem in your query is:

- You're enclosing a human readable filed name in double quotation marks `"`. That's not permissible and you should enclose it within square brackets `[]`.

Your query would thus look like this:

```
SELECT [ER Root].[Network Indicator], 
[ER Root].[Prov Indicator], 
[ER Root].[Pos Indicator], 
Nz([ER].[ER Visit],0) AS [ER Visit]
FROM [ER Root] 
LEFT JOIN ER ON ([ER Root].[Network Indicator] = ER.[Network Flag]) AND
([ER Root].[Pos Indicator] = ER.[POS Indicator]) AND 
([ER Root].[Prov Indicator] = ER.[Category Indicator]);
```

In case you're not running this query directly within the Access application itself, but rather in some external application that uses Access database through `ADO`, `JET`, `DAO`, `ODBC`, or any other external Access driver, you should also note that `NZ` isn't supported through these drivers. `IIF` however is and you could select your `ER Visit` as:

```
IIF([ER].[ER Visit] Is Null, 0, [ER].[ER Visit]) AS [ER Visit]
```

If however you're trying directly in Access then you shouldn't have problems using the `NZ` function.

Cheers!